# WiX Burn after restart/force reboot continuing installation

Tags: wix, installation, windows-xp, burn, wix3.7

I have a WiX [Burn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Burn) custom installer using ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost. After installing one of the prerequisite Microsoft [Windows Installer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) 4.5  I forcefully reboot the PC (Windows XP) using:

```
<ExitCode Behavior="forceReboot"/>
```

The Bundle chain looks like this:

```
<Chain>
   <PackageGroupRef Id="WindowsInstaller45"/>
   <PackageGroupRef Id="Netfx2Full"/>
   <PackageGroupRef Id="Netfx4Full"/>
   <PackageGroupRef Id="CustomPkg"/>
   <PackageGroupRef Id="SQLExpress"/>
</Chain>
```

After it reboots, I want my installation to continue after that, but it actually detects the installation and shows Uninstall option.

How can I detect an unfinished installation when reboot happens during installation?

Comment: What does your chain look like in your bundle and what version of wix are you using?

Comment: I am using Wix 3.7 my chain is as follows 
      <PackageGroupRef Id="WindowsInstaller45"/>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="Netfx2Full"/> 
      <PackageGroupRef Id="Netfx4Full"/>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="CustomPkg"/>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="SQLExpress"/>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the Bundle is started again after a restart the `BOOTSTRAPPER_COMMAND` struct passed to your `BootstrapperApplicationCreate` function contains a `resumeType` field that will be set to `BOOTSTRAPPER_RESUME_TYPE_REBOOT`. In managed code, the `BootstrapperApplication` class contains a `Command` property that contains the `resume` field.

For example in managed code, to tell that your `BootstrapperApplication` started after a restart, you can check:

```
 if (BootstrapperApplication.Command.resume == ResumeType.Reboot)
 {
    // started after restart, go straight to Detect->Plan->Apply to finish the
    // previous operation. BootstrapperApplication.Command.action will tell us
    // the action to complete.
 }
 else
 {
    // started normally, show typical UI scenarios.
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Rob! Should i check for the same in this.Engine.Detect(); in Run

Comment: Yeah, you'll want to check that in Run() or something similarly early.

Comment: Thanks Rob! it worked perfectly as expected after above implementation

Comment: Where is the "Managed Code" in a Bootstrapper   ?