# How can a WiX Burn managed bootstrapper handle force reboots?

Tags: wix, restart, burn, wix3.8

I am creating a managed bootstrapper application with [WiX Burn](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_dotnet.html).  I need to handle some [ExePackage elements](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/exepackage.html) which may require a forced restart.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166186/wix-burn-after-restart-force-reboot-continuing-installation) has some tantalizing clues about how to handle the restart, but I'm having trouble getting it working.

I have `<ExitCode Value="3010" Behavior="forceReboot" />` in the `ExePackage` elements, and I can see that triggering in the logs.  I am listening to the `Shutdown` event that is raised by the `BootstrapperApplication` and setting `e.Result = Result.Restart`, though I haven't figured out how to capture the condition for when this should occur when the force reboot is detected in the Apply phase.  I am testing `if (Command.Resume == ResumeType.Reboot)` in the `Run` method of my `BootstrapperApplication` going straight to the progress bar portion of my custom UI, but I'm not sure how to resume the Apply phase where it left off.  Do I need to call `Engine.Detect()` or `Engine.Apply` in this case?  Is there some special action I need to take to persist and restore the state to survive the reboot, or does the Burn engine handle all of that internally?

If anyone could point me to a working example of a WiX Burn managed bootstrapper application that handles reboots, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the implementation of [WixStandardBA](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/BalExtension/wixstdba/WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.cpp), even though it's not managed.  Basically it does the following:

1. At startup, check the `WixBundleForcedRestartPackage` variable and store it in `m_sczAfterForcedRestartPackage`.
2. Call `Detect` like normal.
3. Call `Plan` like normal.
4. In `OnPlanPackageBegin`, skip packages until the package that caused the restart.
5. Call `Apply` like normal.

Burn takes care of persisting the variables across the restart.

Comment: Thanks, Sean.  I think your answer has brought me very close, but it looks to me like Burn is not persisting variables across the restart.  I have several variables declared like this: `<Variable Name="InstallProductN" Type="string" Value="" Persisted="yes" />`.  I can see these getting set to "yes" when the user opts to install that product in the managed bootstrapper UI, but then it gets reinitialized to an empty string after the reboot.  Do I need to do something in my managed bootstrapper code to trigger the save or restore of the variable state?

Comment: Ah, I had code that was setting the variables to 'yes' if the product was detected and 'no' if not.  This was overriding the restored state.  It is curious that the Burn logs show the variable being initialized to an empty string after the restart but never show the persisted value being restored - unless you specifically output the value to the log later.  But in any case, it is working now.  Thanks!